# How do I resolve Error: NameError: name 'stream' is not defined (PyAudio, Python, RaspberryPi)

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gpio, pyaudio, portaudio

I am recreating the project from this link:
[PYAUDIO record interrupt - Rotary Phone](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=331484)

I have everything wired up and all the necessary libraries installed. When I run the script (which I have modified accordingly) to play my audio files and lift the hookswitch, the debugger posts the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/brian/Documents/imtest 2 RPi.py", line 48, in on_turn
if stream.is_active():   # time to pause audio
NameError: name 'stream' is not defined

The error occurs during the global paused variable:

Is anyone able to inform me how to fix this please?

Chat GPT says:
The error you are encountering indicates that the variable **`stream`** is not defined within the scope of the **`on_turn`** function. It seems that **`stream`** is defined and used in the **`still_picked_up`** section of your code, but it is not accessible within the **`on_turn`** function.

I have tried implementing the fix it suggests to no avail. Any advice would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

```
global paused
paused = False    # global to track if the audio is skipped
def on_turn(skip):
    global paused
    if stream.is_active():   # time to pause audio
        print ('audio skipped')
        paused = False
```

Full code here:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  
import math, sys, os
import random
import pyaudio
import wave
import multiprocessing
import time
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
from time import sleep, perf_counter
from subprocess import call

#blue wire = 3.3v ; white / green / black = ground ; blue wire = gpio17 ; white wire = gpio27 ; red wire = gpio22

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #this input is if the dial is turning, not at it's resting state 
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #this input counts the number of dial circuits, used to translate the dialed number
GPIO.setup(22,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP) #this input is the receiver switch, if the handset is lifted up or not

GPIO.add_event_detect(22, GPIO.BOTH) #this event is when the handset is lifted)

old_pick_up_state = GPIO.input(22)
pick_up_state = GPIO.input(22)

#global variables
global is_picked_up
is_picked_up = False
global has_recorded
has_recorded = False
global still_picked_up
still_picked_up = False
global shutdown
shutdown = False
global play_menu
play_menu = True
global sexy_noise
sexy_noise = False
global beast_number
beast_number = False
global has_recorded_options
has_recorded_options = False


global paused
paused = False    # global to track if the audio is skipped
def on_turn(skip):
    global paused
    if stream.is_active():   # time to pause audio
        print ('audio skipped')
        paused = False


GPIO.add_event_detect(27, GPIO.BOTH, callback=on_turn) #this event is when the dial is turning

def bigcheck():
    pick_up_state = GPIO.input(22)
    old_pick_up_state = 1
    if pick_up_state != old_pick_up_state:
        if pick_up_state == 1: #the handset is picked up!
            print("handset lifted")
            is_picked_up = True
            old_pick_up_state = 1
        else: #the handset is put down
            print("handset down")
            is_picked_up = False
            global still_picked_up
            still_picked_up = False
            global has_recorded
            has_recorded = False
            global has_recorded_options
            has_recorded_options = False
            play_menu = True
            old_pick_up_state = 0
            call(["amixer", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "100%+"])
            return


c=0 
last = 1

def count(pin):
    global c 
    c = c + 1
#this c and count script is used in translating the dialed number

while True:
    
    pick_up_state = GPIO.input(22)
    if pick_up_state != old_pick_up_state:
        if pick_up_state == 1: #the handset is picked up!
            print("handset lifted")
            is_picked_up = True
            old_pick_up_state = 1
        else: #the handset is put down
            print("handset down")
            is_picked_up = False
            still_picked_up = False
            has_recorded = False
            play_menu = True
            old_pick_up_state = 0
            call(["amixer", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "100%+"])

    if is_picked_up: #plays the intro upon handset pickup
        sleep(1)
        call(["amixer", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "100%+"])
        random_intro = random.choice(os.listdir("/home/pi/Music/Rotary_Recordings/mcgrath/")) #chooses one of the four intro recordings
        intro = AudioSegment.from_wav("/home/pi/Music/Rotary_Recordings/mcgrath/"+random_intro)
        intro2 = intro - 20
        print('playing intro')
        play(intro2)
        still_picked_up = True
        is_picked_up = False
        paused = True
    
    if still_picked_up: #after the intro, goes to the main menu
        if play_menu:
            call(["amixer", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "75%-"])
            wf = wave.open('/home/pi/Music/Rotary_Recordings/menu-options-mcgrath.wav', 'rb') #your audio here
            p = pyaudio.PyAudio() #instantiate PyAudio
            def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status): #define callback
                data = wf.readframes(frame_count)
                return (data, pyaudio.paContinue)
            stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()), #open stream using callback
                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                rate=wf.getframerate(),
                output=True,
                stream_callback=callback)
            stream.start_stream() #start the stream
            while stream.is_active() and paused==True: #wait for stream to finish
                #with on_turn as listener:
                    #listener.join()
                time.sleep(0.1)
            stream.stop_stream() #stop the stream
            stream.close()
            wf.close()
            p.terminate() #close pyaudio
            call(["amixer", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "75%+"])
            paused = True
            print('played menu')
            play_menu = False

        try:        
            if GPIO.event_detected(27):
                current = GPIO.input(27)
                if(last != current):
                    if(current == 0):
                        GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.BOTH, callback=count, bouncetime=10)
                    else:
                        GPIO.remove_event_detect(17)
                        number = int((c)/2)
                        print ("You dial", number)
                        c= 0

                        
                        if(number == 1):#code for the prefice audio and recording a message
                            prefice = AudioSegment.from_wav("/home/pi/Music/Rotary_Recordings/prefice-mcgrath.wav")
                            prefice2 = prefice - 20
                            prefice_beep = AudioSegment.from_wav("/home/pi/Music/Rotary_Recordings/beep.wav")
                            prefice_beep2 = prefice_beep - 20
                            print('playing prefice')
                            play(prefice2)
                            play(prefice_beep2)
                            print('prefice played now recording')
                            try:
                                file = open('count.txt','r')
                                n = int(file.read())
                                file.close()
                            except IOError:
                                file = open('count.txt','w')
                                file.write('1')
                                file.close()
                                n = 1
                            print(n)

                            n += 1

                            with open('count.txt','w') as file:
                                file.write(str(n))
                            print("Now the variable n persists and is incremented every time.")
                            #Do what you want to do further, the value of n will increase every time you run the program
                            
                            has_recorded = True
                            has_recorded_options = True
                            play_menu = True
                            
                            start_rtime = perf_counter()
                            
                            chunk = 1024  # Record in chunks of 1024 samples
                            sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16  # 16 bits per sample
                            channels = 2
                            fs = 44100  # Record at 44100 samples per second
                            seconds = 30
                            file="/home/pi/Music/Guest Recordings/"
                            wavey=".wav"
                            filename=file+str(n)+wavey

                            p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  # Create an interface to PortAudio

                            print('Recording')

                            stream = p.open(format=sample_format,
                                            channels=channels,
                                            rate=fs,
                                            frames_per_buffer=chunk,
                                            input=True)

                            frames = []  # Initialize array to store frames

                            # Store data in chunks for 3 seconds
                            for i in range(0, int(fs / chunk * seconds)):
                                data = stream.read(chunk)
                                frames.append(data)
                                bigcheck()
                                if still_picked_up==False:
                                    break

                            # Stop and close the stream 
                            stream.stop_stream()
                            stream.close()
                            # Terminate the PortAudio interface
                            p.terminate()

                            print('Finished recording')

                            # Save the recorded data as a WAV file
                            wf = wave.open(filename, 'wb')
                            wf.setnchannels(channels)
                            wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(sample_format))
                            wf.setframerate(fs)
                            wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
                            wf.close()

                            end_rtime = perf_counter()
                            print(f'This recording length is {end_rtime- start_rtime: 0.2f} second(s).')
                            
                            print("potential recording")
                            still_picked_up = False
                            
                            #play loud beep denoting end
                            message_end_beep = AudioSegment.from_wav("/home/pi/Music/Rotary_Recordings/beep.wav")
                            message_end_beep2 = message_end_beep - 20
                            print('playing message end beep')
                            play(message_end_beep2)
                            
                        if(number == 2):#python code to play a random guest recording from the recording folder
                            #call(["amixer", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "100%+"])
                            random_recording1 = random.choice(os.listdir("/home/pi/Music/Guest Recordings/"))
                            random_recording2 = "/home/pi/Music/Guest Recordings/"+random_recording1
                            #random_recording3 = random_recording2 - 20
                            print("playing recorded " + random_recording1)
                            
                            call(["amixer", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "80%-"])
                            
                            wf = wave.open(random_recording2, 'rb') #your audio here
                            p = pyaudio.PyAudio() #instantiate PyAudio
                            def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status): #define callback
                                data = wf.readframes(frame_count)
                                return (data, pyaudio.paContinue)
                            stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(wf.getsampwidth()), #open stream using callback
                                channels=wf.getnchannels(),
                                rate=wf.getframerate(),
                                output=True,
                                stream_callback=callback)
                            stream.start_stream() #start the stream
                            while stream.is_active() and paused==True: #wait for stream to finish
                                #with on_turn as listener:
                                    #listener.join()
                                time.sleep(0.1)
                            stream.stop_stream() #stop the stream
                            stream.close()
                            wf.close()
                            p.terminate() #close pyaudio
                            call(["amixer", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "80%+"])
                            paused = True
                            
                            play_menu = True
                            sleep(1)
                            
                        if(number == 5):#this number plays a random song from the song library (McGrath choice = Matrix operator)
                            #songnumber = random.randint(2, 8)
                            #randomsong = "/home/pi/Music/Songs/"+str(songnumber)+".wav"
                            #randomsong2 = randomsong - 10
                            matrix = "/home/pi/Music/Rotary_Recordings/Matrix-mcgrath.wav"
                            print('playing Matrix using pydub')
                            call(["amixer", "-D", "pulse", "sset"
```

I have extremely limited coding experience and have been leaning hard on Chat GPT.

The error you are encountering indicates that the variable `stream` is not defined within the scope of the `on_turn` function. It seems that `stream` is defined and used in the `still_picked_up` section of your code, but it is not accessible within the `on_turn` function.

To resolve this issue, you need to make the `stream` variable accessible to the `on_turn` function. One way to achieve this is by passing the `stream` variable as an argument to the `on_turn` function when registering the event detection callback.

Here's an updated version of the relevant code snippet:

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
# ... (other imports)

# Define global variable 'stream'
stream = None

# ... (other code)

def on_turn(pin):
    global paused
    global stream

    if stream is not None and stream.is_active():
        print('Audio skipped')
        paused = False

# ... (other code)

GPIO.add_event_detect(27, GPIO.BOTH, callback=on_turn, bouncetime=200)

# ... (rest of the code)
```

In this modified code, we define the `stream` variable as a global variable before the `on_turn` function. Then, we modify the `on_turn` function to access the `stream` variable using the `global` keyword.

Additionally, note that I added the `bouncetime` argument with a value of 200 when calling `GPIO.add_event_detect`. This helps to debounce the event detection to prevent false triggers due to signal fluctuations.

By making these changes, the `on_turn` function should now be able to access the `stream` variable without throwing the `NameError` you encountered.

Code post ChatGPT recommended edits:

```
global stream
stream = None


global paused
paused = False    # global to track if the audio is skipped
def on_turn(pin):
    global paused
    global stream
    if stream is not None and stream.is_active():   # time to pause audio
        print ('audio skipped')
        paused = False


GPIO.add_event_detect(27, GPIO.BOTH, callback=on_turn, bouncetime=200) #this event is when the dial is turning

def bigcheck():
    pick_up_state = GPIO.input(22)
    old_pick_up_state = 1
    if pick_up_state != old_pick_up_state:
        if pick_up_state == 1: #the handset is picked up!
            print("handset lifted")
            is_picked_up = True
            old_pick_up_state = 1
        else: #the handset is put down
            print("handset down")
            is_picked_up = False
            global still_picked_up
            still_picked_up = False
            global has_recorded
            has_recorded = False
            global has_recorded_options
            has_recorded_options = False
            play_menu = True
            old_pick_up_state = 0
            call(["amixer", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "100%+"])
            return


c=0 
last = 1

def count(pin):
    global c 
    c = c + 1
#this c and count script is used in translating the dialed number

while True:
    
    pick_up_state = GPIO.input(22)
    if pick_up_state != old_pick_up_state:
        if pick_up_state == 1: #the handset is picked up!
            print("handset lifted")
            is_picked_up = True
            old_pick_up_state = 1
        else: #the handset is put down
            print("handset down")
            is_picked_up = False
            still_picked_up = False
            has_recorded = False
            play_menu = True
            old_pick_up_state = 0
            call(["amixer", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "100%+"])

    if is_picked_up: #plays the intro upon handset pickup
        sleep(1)
        call(["amixer", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "100%+"])
        intro = AudioSegment.from_wav("/home/brian/Music/Rotary_Recordings/Intro.wav")
        print('playing intro')
        play(intro)
        still_picked_up = True
        is_picked_up = False
        paused = True
```

Comment: So, if you have an answer, what is your question here?

Comment: I have tried to implement the answer chatGPT gave unsuccessfully. I am not even sure if it is the correct answer. My question is what modifications do I need to make to the code to make it work? I was hoping someone would reply with something like "try adding these lines of code here and let me know if it works." Please forgive my asking for a bit of hand-holding as I am very new to all of this. Trying to complete this project for my wedding.

Comment: But what's the problem?  The code down below clearly does not get the `name "stream" is not defined` error, because it is defined.  From your question, we can't tell what your CURRENT code is, and we can't tell what does and does not work.  Honestly, you might consider deleting this question and asking another that is better organized.  I'm not tring to be mean, but the question is really unclear.

Comment: I will post what the code looks like post when implementing the changes from ChatGPT at the bottom of my original question to show the current state of the code. The issue I am having is that prior to implementing the changes I would get the stream error immediately after picking up the hook switch indicating that picking up the phone was at least being registered. After the changes nothing happens. Ultimately my goal is to have it when I lift the phone off the hook switch the audio file ("/home/brian/Music/Rotary_Recordings/Intro.wav") plays when I pick up the phone.